# Is there a reward for killing the fire lizard at the bottom of the Forest of Fallen Giants?

Tags: dark-souls-2

This is my first playthrough of Dark Souls 2, so I decided to ask it here and avoid looking on wiki to avoid any spoilers.

After reaching the bottom of Cardinal Tower, there are two caves. In one of them is fire lizard which casts fireballs at us and a fire sword to get from the chest.

I bought a bow and killed the lizard, then I noticed it left some drop, unfortunately I couldnt jump in there (I realize there exist a way to get there, but not from here) and get it. Im not sure it disappeared or not, but did I lose something crucial? Or it was a simple(common) drop from a monster?

Comment: The portal 2 wiki had a button that would toggle spoilers. I wish most other game wikis had this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, these flame lizards don't really drop anything special. They definitely don't drop anything unique to those flame lizards specifically. However, you can use these flame lizards to get yourself a nice amount of souls early on, as each one drops **3,325** souls.

From [the wikia](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Flame+Lizard) (don't worry, these aren't spoilers):

> General: The two in the pit under Cardinal Tower bonfire can be sniped. They are high hp, so it can take a while. For the ones in the lair, try luring them back to the lair entry-way. At some point, they'll start to back off, and you can get good hits in. Rinse and repeat for easy Soul Farming. Contains a weak spot on their underside just above what would be their collarbone. When hit, it pretty much doubles the damage it takes.

Additionally, although these flame lizards don't drop anything spectacular or missable, there are some good items in that pit, though you may want to wait until later in the game before you attempt to pick them up.

From the [wikia page on this specific area](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Forest+of+Fallen+Giants#FlameLizardPit), it looks like you can get the following items:

> In the first section you can find a corpse with a [Firedrake Stone](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Firedrake+Stone), a skull holding a Soul of a Proud Knight, a skeleton with the [Hawk Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Hawk+Ring) (which seems to be mostly useless) and a chest carrying a [Flame Quartz Ring +1](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Flame+Quartz+Ring). In the lower area, a corpse holds Cracked Red Eye Orb x2. In the area with the last Flame Lizard (who tend to drop Cracked Red Eye Orbs as well) there is a skeleton carrying the [Rebel's Greatshield](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Rebel%27s+Greatshield).